# Hibernate Formula doesn't allow any custom Java code in Getter

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have the following Hibernate formula, which works, but the custom `WordUtils.capitalizeFully` modifier in the Getter does not work. I need to not only get the value of the formula but then also apply the custom Java code to it. Is there a way to do it? My result does not have the modification.

```
@Formula("case when preferred_first_name is not null then preferred_first_name else first_name end || ' ' || case when preferred_last_name is not null then preferred_last_name else last_name end")
public String getFullNameFL() {
    return WordUtils.capitalizeFully(fullNameFL);
}
```

This is used in a JPA Projection,

```
CompoundSelection<ResultBean> selection = cb.construct(
   ResultBean.class,
   ...
   nvRoot.get("fullNameFL"),
   ...

criteriaQuery.select(selection);
TypedQuery<ResultBean> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<ResultBean> results = query.getResultList();
```